# Page reloading before completing the operation (most of the times) - Vue and Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

Something is wrong. There is no error, but when I push the button, it is rarely loading the page with the updated status. it happens in two separate similar components in a POS app. I want to change the current seller, using a button in the sellers table.

**SELLERS COMPONENT- HTML. INSIDE THE TABLE**

```
  <tbody class="text-left">
    <tr v-for="(seller, index) in sellers" :key="index">
      <td v-if="!seller.active">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" @click="activateSeller(seller)">
          <i class="fas fa-user-check"></i>
        </button>
      </td>
      <td v-if="seller.active">
        <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
activateSeller(seller) {
  db.collection("sellers")
    .where("active", "==", true)
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        db.collection("sellers")
          .doc(doc.id)
          .set(
            {
              active: false
            },
            { merge: true }
          );
      });
    })
    .then(() => {
      db.collection("sellers")
        .where("number", "==", `${seller.number}`)
        .get()
        .then(snapshot => {
          snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
            db.collection("sellers")
              .doc(doc.id)
              .set(
                {
                  active: true
                },
                { merge: true }
              );
          });
        });
    })
    .then(() => {
      location.reload();
    })

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should correctly [chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Chaining) the different promises as well as use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait that all the parallel writes are completed, as follows:

```
  function activateSeller(seller) {
    const sellerColl = db.collection('sellers');

    sellerColl
      .where('active', '==', true)
      .get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        const promises = [];
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          promises.push(doc.ref.set({ active: false }, { merge: true }));
        });
        return Promise.all(promises);
      })
      .then(() => {
        return sellerColl.where('number', '==', `${seller.number}`).get();
      })
      .then(snapshot => {
        const promises = [];
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          promises.push(doc.ref.set({ active: true }, { merge: true }));
        });
        return Promise.all(promises);
      })
      .then(() => {
        location.reload();
      });
  }
```

---

Note that instead of `Promise.all()` you could use a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions?authuser=0#batched-writes), but be aware that there is a limit of maximum 500 operations within one batched write.

---

Note also that you may end your promises chain by a `catch()`, in order to manage errors and inform your end user.